# How to intersect multidimensional arrays without manual iteration?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional arrays, example:

```
array(
  'a' => array(
    'code1' => array('v1', 'v2'),
    'code2' => array('v1', 'v2')
  ),
  'b' => array(
    'code3' => array('v1', 'v2'),
    'code4' => array('v1', 'v2'),
    'code5' => array('v1', 'v2'),
    'code6' => array('v1', 'v2')
  )
)
```

and

```
array(
  'a' => array(
    'code1' => '',
  ),
  'b' => array(
    'code5' => ''
  )
)
```

My desired result is:

```
array(
  'a' => array(
    'code1' => array('v1', 'v2')
  ),
  'b' => array(
    'code5' => array('v1', 'v2')
  )
)
```

I'm pretty sure it could be possible using one of built-in php functions, however I'm stuck with it, and can't find a solution rather than manually iterating through array. 
Can you help me with that?

Comment: Read your question many times unable to get your request

Comment: not sure why you don't understand my request. I gave you two input arrays, and my desired result from it. Simple array_intersect family functions won't work, because it's multidimensional array. I would like to know if there's any other function that could produce output array without manually iterating through arrays

Comment: @Marrbacca What do you mean by manual iteration? There's no built-in function for intersection in all situations. Sometimes, you have to use a loop, and there's nothing "wrong" with that. Jon's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact solution would depend on what you want to happen if the two arrays don't exactly match key-wise, but one way to reach your desired result is:

```
$a = array(
  'a' => array(
    'code1' => array('v1', 'v2'),
    'code2' => array('v1', 'v2')
  ),
  'b' => array(
    'code3' => array('v1', 'v2'),
    'code4' => array('v1', 'v2'),
    'code5' => array('v1', 'v2'),
    'code6' => array('v1', 'v2')
  )
);

$b = array(
  'a' => array(
    'code1' => '',
  ),
  'b' => array(
    'code5' => ''
  )
);

$result = array();
foreach ($a as $key => $data) {
    $result[$key] = array_intersect_key($data, $b[$key]);
}
```

The idea is to use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to keep only those elements from `$a` that appear (as keys) in `$b`.

Comment: keys in both array will always match - your solution is much closer to what I needed, thanks :). I was also trying to achieve this using array_uintersect functions with callback to remove every foreach. Do you think it could be possible?

Comment: @Marrbacca: No, `array_uintersect` only lets you specify the comparison logic -- it doesn't let you do custom processing.

Comment: that's what I thought, I asked the question to confirm. Thank you for your solution, it's correct and working perfectly :)